# Isset function for buttons in php code

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

How can I make the form not to run the php code directly when the database.php is executed. I can set an if clause that `if isset then run..`  but there is nothing in the form except the `show` button. Is there any way to test if the show button is set? what is the `isset` for buttons?

below is the code

```
database.php
<?php
        require 'core.inc.php';
        require 'conn.inc.php';


        if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
        {
            $query= "SELECT *  FROM Properties";

            $query_run=mysql_query($query);

            if ($num=mysql_num_rows($query_run))
            {
                echo $num, " results found <br>";

                while ($query_row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                {
                    echo "Found";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>      
    <html>
            <div >
                <form action='<?php echo $current_file;?>' method='POST'>
                <input type="submit" value="Show">
                </form>
            </div> 
    </html>
```

Comment: I don't entirely understand what you want to happen when, but if you give your button a name, `name="showbutton"`, then you should be able to check `isset($_POST['showbutton'])` to see if it was clicked, i.e. the form was submitted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this..

```
<?php
            require 'core.inc.php';
            require 'conn.inc.php';

       if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            if (isset($_SESSION['user_id']) && !empty($_SESSION['user_id']))
            {
                $query= "SELECT *  FROM Properties";

                $query_run=mysql_query($query);

                if ($num=mysql_num_rows($query_run))
                {
                    echo $num, " results found <br>";
                    while ($query_row= mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run))
                      echo "Found";
                  }
               }
            }
        ?>      
        <html>
                <div>
                    <form action='<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>' method='POST'>
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Show">
                    </form>
                </div> 
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a name to your submit button. e.g btnsubmit than check condition if(isset($_POST['btnsubmit'])). It must work, except this everything is pretty good with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add a hidden input to your HTML inside the `<form>` like this:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="action" value="asdf" />
```

Then in your PHP you can check:

```
if (isset($_POST['action']) && $_POST['action'] === 'asdf') {
   // Something
} else {
   // Something else
}
```

Use this to branch your code logic, though if it gets really long I'd recommend using multiple files.

Comment: Why ````===````? Shouldn't ````==```` be enough? (Don't get me wrong, I'm just curious)

Comment: Why should i have two separate $_POSTs?

Comment: `==` would be enough in this case, but it is good practice to use `===` when comparing strings in PHP that you are certain will not contain numbers.  Newbie I don't understand your question, there is only one `$_POST`, you are just including an extra `<input>` tag.